# Java Grouping by inner list value

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
class A {    
    private Collection<B> b;    
}

class B {
    String field;
    private Collection<C> c;
}

class C {
    String Name;
}
```

Now I want to check the value which is there in class `C` (Name) is equal or not by looping collection `B` and passing `name` as an argument. How do we achieve this using streams in Java?

Comment: After check what do you want then? Get a list of A contains have that String name in C or?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. A `Map<String, A>`? How do you want to deal with the fact that it's a nested collection? Duplicate `A`?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn yes I want list of C

Comment: Beside showing example of class structure also post example of input/beginning-state and result you expect to get. Without it your question is not very clear.

Comment: You want list `C` that match the name right? What's your input? A or List<A> ?

Comment: if I pass Name as argument it has to retun List of c

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result as follows:

```
List<C> result = myList.stream()
            .flatMap(a -> a.getB().stream())
            .flatMap(b -> b.getC().stream())
            .filter(c -> Objects.equals(c.getName(), searchName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This creates a stream from myList (`List<A>`) and then consecutively flattens the nested collections to get a `Stream<C>` and then returns the `C` objects that have the provided `searchName` and then finally collects it to a list instance.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a list `C` by filtering list `A` whose name equals `yourName`

```
List<A> listA = ...

List<C> filteredA = listA.stream()
     .map(A::getB)
     .flatMap(Collection::stream)
     .map(B::getC)
     .flatMap(Collection::stream)
     .filter(c -> yourName.equals(c.getName()))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You're welcome. Later please clearly said your expected output and input :)